# UIViewController doesn't get deallocated after being popped from a navigation controller, if the action starts from a UIAlertView delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

would you please look at that piece of code:

```
/* This app is a game, the user can click an "abort" button anytime,
 * and he/she is therefore asked for confirmation ("really abort game?")
 */
- (IBAction)btnAbortClicked:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [alert setMessage:@"Really abort game?"];
    [alert setDelegate:self];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

/* Delegate method (I don't like it, I wish I had modal blocking windows) */
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    [self quitGame];
}

/* pop the view controller */
- (void)quitGame {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The problem is simple - but apparently not enough for me to solve. The UIViewController gets popped, but doesn't get deallocated. And the problem is strictly related to the UIAlertView, because if I just call quitGame from btnAbortClicked:, the view controller is popped and immediately deallocated.

Instead, it seems some mysterious entity retains it.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry guys I'm a total moron. That was a stupid timer not being deactivated that was still keeping the view controller in life. The problem is indeed not related to the UIAlertView, it's just by chance: when the user completes the game w/o aborting, the timer is correctly invalidated, and so it's ok. When the user aborts the game, I just forgot to invalidate the timer as well. Sorry for wasting your time guys

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that you're still inside the alertView when clickedButtonAtIndex is called.  I'd suggest moving to alertView:disDismissWithButtonIndex instead, so that you're called after the alertview disappears.